# Eclipse run uiautomator with command '-e debug true' not working

Tags: eclipse, android-uiautomator

I have aearched some many docs in network and didn't see anyone encountered this problem. My question is:

Finished coding and build.xml building with:

1. android create uitest-project -n projectname -t 1 -p prjectpath
2. ant build
3. push the .jar to mobile
4. adb shell uiautomator runtest xx.jar -e debug true -c packagename.classname

The problem coming when I running the last command, follow up the rule and guile, device should be access debug mode "sending wait chunk" with command "-e debug true", but the problem is the program go ahead directly without "sending wait chunk" then result in I can not use DDMS remote debug my program.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported per [announcement](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html).

Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate your projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrate to [Android Studio from Eclipse](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html).

Also, you should use [Testing Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html) to run and or debug UiAutomator tests from Android Studio and you won't have any problems.